# No route matches [DELETE] "/follows" rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an rails application that I am working on following and unfollowing a user right not I have the create method working but not the delete method and I do not know why I am getting this error.

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         
  has_many :post
  has_many :likes
  has_many :follows
  acts_as_commontator
end

                               
                               
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```html
<% @users.try(:each) do |user| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= user.email %></td>
          <td>
            <% if follow = user.follows.find_by(follows: user.id) %>
                <%= link_to 'Unfollow', follows_path({user_id: user.id}), method: :delete%>
                <%= link_to 'Unfollow', follows_path({user_id: user.id}), method: 'delete',class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to 'Follow', follows_path({user_id: user.id}), method: 'post',class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

```html
class FollowsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    follow = Follow.new
    follow.user_id = current_user.id
    follow.follows = params[:user_id]
    follow.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    follow = Follow.where('user_id = ? AND follows = ?',current_user.id,params[:user_id])
    Follow.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

I don't know why the method is not working.

the user_id field is the field of the current logged in user, and the follows field it the user that the user follows.

Comment: Can you post the relevant section from your routes file?

Comment: devise_for :users
  resources :likes
  delete 'follows/:user_id' => 'follows#destroy'
  resources :posts
  resources :follows
  mount Commontator::Engine => '/commontator'
  root 'news_feed#index'

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the route that maps the http method (delete) and url (generated from the follows_path and user_id) to the relevant controller action.

In your routes.rb file add the following:

```
delete 'follows/:user_id' => 'follows#destroy'
```

Comment: I have the resources :post in my routes though

Comment: posts? ok I'm confused ... I thought you were getting the error in the FollowsController when trying to unfollow. Where does the posts come into this then?

Comment: Sorry i meant resources :follows

Comment: yeah but by default that creates `delete 'follows/:id' => 'follows#destroy'` or something similar ... you need to override it if you want to use `:user_id`. Type `rake routes` in console and you will see the generated routes.

Comment: How would i write the method to use the regenerated routes

Comment: you mean the auto generated route or the one i posted? For the one I posted no change... for the auto generated one from `resources follows` you will need to change in your controller from reading `params[:user_id]` to reading `params[:id]` - and also change all the links in your views ... instead of `follows_path({user_id: user.id})`, it should be `follow_path(id: user.id)`

Comment: So that it works with the method a wrote to destroy a record.

Answer (score 0):

Change `follows_path` to singular to access the DELETE path for that resource:

```
<%= link_to 'Unfollow', follow_path({user_id: user.id}), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"follows", :user_id=>1} missing required keys: [:id]